# Rewriting index.php in CodeIgniter isn't working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have already tried all the possible solutions that I've find in SO, but I still unable to load my controllers without adding the index.php/ before (CodeIgniter), I'm not even able to load my default controller as CI throws a 404 error.

I am using *CI 2.1.3*

**My config is as follows:**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; //tested all the options
```

**My .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for you time.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for :**

> " but I still unable to load my controllers without adding the
>   index.php/ before (CodeIgniter), I'm not even able to load my default
>   controller as CI throws a 404 error."

Use this .htaccess in your main folder i.e where the application is in.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I already have those lines in my .htcaccess, yes it is in my main folder, and I've also tried to put only that.

Comment: I hope the NamingConvention is all right, and In config.php $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myproject/'; is set

Comment: $config['index_page'] = '';

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Linux Server add this code in your .htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

application/config/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

To

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```